# What drush version I can use that doesn't require composer?

Tags: drush

I try to use drush on the server that is behind corporate firewall, and downloads from many sites are blocked. In particular, when I run "composer diag", it hangs for the long time on the line "Checking http connectivity to packagist: http://packagist.org/" and then prints "The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream". I saw similar blockage when trying to use wget with a number of URLs, including ftp-origin.drupal.org/files/projects/.

So how far back should I go to get the version of drush that doesn't use composer and will not try to update itself on the first run? I understand that some functionality will be missing, but at least basic functions like "drush cc", "drush en", "drush dis", etc. I will be able to use.

Comment: I am not aware of Drush using composer, but  I never paid attention to it. Just realize that Drush versions are bound to Drupal versions. If you have a Drupal 8 site, you cannot use any Drush version < 8. See http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#drupal-compatibility UPDATE: It indeed seems that Drush 9 is composer based.

Comment: I am on Drupal 7 site and I know in the past drush did not require composer. I just don't know how far back.

Answer (score 1):

I believe any version on this page that is released as a `phar` file:
https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases

Super old versions of Drush (unsupported) were not released as single phar files. The current version of drush (version 9) seems to be geared to released/maintained via Composer only; and no longer Pecl or other distribution channels.

Comment: Even the version 8.1.12 has a phar file, and for sure we know that drush 8.x requires composer. We have to go way back to the version that doesn't use composer, but I couldn't find in the release notes where they would say "from now on composer is required".

Comment: @VladimirIvanov If you have a Drush.phar file, that doesn't require Composer. Drush uses Composer just as a way to be installed, not for doing anything else. Drush 8.x recommends to install it with Composer, but you don't have to install it with Composer.